# How do I declare a dynamic array with std::auto_ptr?

Tags: c++, arrays, auto-ptr

I am trying to declare a dynamic `int` array like below:

```
int n;
int *pInt = new int[n];
```

Can I do this with `std::auto_ptr`?

I tried something like:

```
std::auto_ptr<int> pInt(new int[n]);
```

But it doesn't compile.

I'm wondering if I could declare a dynamic array with `auto_ptr` construct and how. Thanks!

Comment: [Worked for me...](http://ideone.com/7MlK7)

Comment: @SethCarnegie: For a very loose definition of "Worked". Compiled, yes. Undefined behavior? *Absolutely.*

Comment: @NicolBolas oh yeah, forgot about that. However, I still don't know why it didn't compile for him.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, you cannot, and it will not: C++98 is very limited when it comes to arrays, and `auto_ptr` is a very awkward beast that often doesn't do what you need.

You can:

- use `std::vector<int>`/`std::deque<int>`, or `std::array<int, 10>`, or
- use C++11 and `std::unique_ptr<int[]> p(new int[15])`, or
- use C++11 and `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>>` (though that feels too complicated for `int`).

If the size of the array is known at compile time, use one of the static containers (`array` or an array-unique-pointer). If you have to modify the size at runtime, basically use `vector`, but for larger classes you can also use a vector of unique-pointers.

`std::unique_ptr` is what `std::auto_ptr` wanted to be but couldn't due to the limitations of the language.

Comment: Sorry for this dumb question, but `std::unique_ptr` can handle arrays as well as single objects properly then, right?

Comment: @SethCarnegie: Yes, it can, and it even provides `[]`-access for arrays. (And it prohibits upgrading to `shared_ptr`.)

Comment: @Kerrek: Thanks. Is the array length considered known at compile time in the following code: `void foo(int n) {int *pInt = new int[n];} int main() { foo(10); }` Thanks.

Comment: @itnovice: no, it isn't. C++ doesn't have a sufficiently sophisticated notion of a "constant expression". What you would have to do is `template <unsigned int n> void foo() { int a[n]; }; int main() { foo<10>(); }`

Comment: `std::unique_ptr` can be used for variable sizes. `int i = 10; std::unique_ptr<int[]> p(new int[i]);` would be OK.

Comment: @itnovice: Sorry for my mental block; thanks to fefe's comment, what you *can* do is `void foo(int n) { std::unique_ptr<int[]> p(new int[n]); }`. That's basically the safe, dynamic version of the  code in your comment.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot. `std::auto_ptr` cannot handle dynamic arrays, as the reallocation is different (`delete` vs `delete[]`).

But I wonder what the compilation error may be ...

Comment: Thanks. The compiler errors look like `temp.cpp:19: error: no match for ‘operator[]’ in ‘pInt[0]’
temp.cpp:21: error: no match for ‘operator[]’ in ‘pInt[i]’
temp.cpp:21: error: no match for ‘operator[]’ in ‘pInt[(i - 1)]’`

Comment: @itnovice yeah, because you're trying to use (something that thinks it is) a pointer to a single object as an array. As has been said, `auto_ptr` is for single objects so it doesn't have `operator[]`.